# How do I set color of map dots in Carto Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, carto

I'm using Carto JS API.

```
        function main() {
            // create leaflet map and define some properties
            var map=    L.map(
                "map",
                {
                    zoomControl: true,
                    center: [40,-95],
                    zoom: 4
                }
            );

            // add a base layer to map
            var Hydda_Full = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.se/hydda/full/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: 'Tiles courtesy of <a href="http://openstreetmap.se/" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap Sweden</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
            });
            Hydda_Full.addTo(map);

            // viz.json of map
            var layerURL=           "URL TO MY CARTO MAP GOES HERE";

            cartodb.createLayer(map, layerURL, {infowindow: false, tooltip: false})
                .addTo(map)
                .done(function(layer){
                    layer.setInteraction(true);
                }
       }
```

This gives me my map with dots. The default color is orange. I want to change their colors in the JS API. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the `layer` object you receive in the `.done` method, you will be able to get to the sublayers (your map can have several layers) and then run [`.setCartoCSS`](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js/api-methods#sublayersetcartocsscss) to change dynamically the cartographic rules. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SzMbyj?p=preview) you have an example of changing both the CartoCSS and the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setCartoCSS` method. [Here](http://bit.ly/createLayer-cartojs) you can find a working example. But the key lines are these:

```
sublayer.setCartoCSS(new_style);
```

Where `sublayer` has been previously declared using `getSubLayer` method and `new_style` is a variable storing your new style.